# Rails: SuperClass Mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, superclass

I'm having trouble starting to build my own admin section. I get this error when trying to view example.com/admin:

```
 TypeError in Admin::AdminController#dashboard

 "superclass mismatch for class AdminController"
```

My admin controller is in app/controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb

Here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


namespace :admin do
    root :to => "admin#dashboard"
    resources :posts
end
```

Here is my AdminController:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def dashboard
  print "Dashboard"
  end
end
```

My plan is to have example.com/admin go to the admin dashboard. To edit/create posts: /admin/posts.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `Admin::AdminController` class defined elsewhere. Which inherits from different class other then `ApplicationController`

If you have not created a second `Admin::AdminController` class yourself, it is likely one of your Gems or plugins already defines it.
If you are using `active_admin` or `rails_admin` gem , maybe it does have class with the above name `AdminController`

You can cross check by replacing the `AdminController` with some other name maybe `AdminController2`

Comment: I do not have an admin gem; i am building my own. I tried renaming AdminController to AdminController2 and got this error: "Superclass mismatch for class AdminController2." My PostController.rb uses "class Admin::PostsController < ApplicationController".  When I change it to "PostController <Application" the error returns to "Superclass mismatch for class AdminController."